# Set result of 2 or more Async HTTP calls into named variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, concurrency, python-asyncio

What I want to achieve is :
`tasks = [call(url) for url in urls]`

`call` is an `async` method / `coroutine` in Python3.5 to perform GET requests , let's say `aiohttp`.

So basically all calls to call are async. Now I can run `asyncio.wait(tasks)` and later access the result in futures one by one.

BUT, what I want is, lets assume there are 2 url only, then :
`a, b = call(url1), call(url2)`

Something like how you do it in Koa by yielding an array. Any help how to do this if it can be done ??

Comment: Do you want the calls to happen simultaneously or sequentially?

Comment: @dim simultaneously

Comment: Then you'll need to use something like `asyncio.wait` or `asyncio.gather`.

Comment: Yeah that I know , but how ? how to assign it to named variables rather than a future array ?

Comment: `var1, var2 = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(task1, task2))`

Comment: @dirn this will ensure the result of task1 goes into var1 and task2 into var2 ?

Comment: According to the docs, `gather` retains the order of the sequence it was passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var1, var2 = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(task1, task2))`

According to the docs, gather retains the order of the sequence it was passed